# Data is showing properly however console is showing "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this function in my `component.ts` which shows the sum total of the column data (weight in this case):

```
getTotalWeight(){
    return ELEMENT_DATA.map(t => t.weight).reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
  }
```

and in my `component.html` I have something like this to call the function to display the total weight:

```
<p>Total weight: {{getTotalWeight()}}</p>
```

The data is indeed showing properly, however in my console, I'm seeing the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at CashPlannerComponent.getTotalAvailableAmount (cash-planner.component.ts:134)
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (CashPlannerComponent.html:145)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:45293)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44276)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44636)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:44564)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44277)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44636)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:44593)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44271)
```

I tried to reproduce the error on stackblitz but the error does not appear on stackblitz. I'm unable to share the source code directly because it's a company app. This [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvmwya) is similar to what I'm doing on my company app.

The `CashPlannerComponent.getTotalAvailableAmount()` function in the error is the one in my company app, for which its usage is the same as `getTotalWeight()` as shown above.

Any idea what is producing this error in my console even though the sum total column data is displaying properly?

*UPDATED:

In my actual source code I'm mapping from an array I got from calling an API:

```
  getPayment() {
    this.paymentService.getPayment(this.currentAccount.accountId).subscribe(
      (data: Payment[]) => {
        this.paymentList = data;
        this.dataSource.data = this.paymentList;
        this.isLoading = false;
      },
      error => {
        this.alertService.error('Could not retrieve the data requested');
      }
    );
  }
```

and using `Array.map()` to get the sum total to display on my html, which is working fine but getting the error described above on the console:

```
getTotalAvailableAmount() {
    return this.paymentList.map(x => x.amount).reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
  }
```

Comment: what is inside `ELEMENT_DATA` and how you are assigning value to it ??

Comment: that's an array,  the ```ELEMENT_DATA``` is the one in the DEMO, in my actual code it's an array list as well. Have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL; DR

Make sure you initialize the `paymentList` with empty value. i.e

`public paymentList : <type>[] = [];`

> Why my code is not working ?

Since JS is Asynchronous, It doesn't wait for any IO request to get completed. Instead it will keep executing next line of codes.

Since you are getting the value from service , the view is getting initialized before the service returns the data. And at that time the value of `paymentList` is `undefined` because you might not have initialized it.

Answer (score 1):

As @programoholic mentioned the problem is with asynchronous code. In your stackblitz it is working because the data is static. To repro the issue I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvmwya-nd7rjv?file=app/table-selection-example.ts) where I am assigning value after 1000ms. To fix, please set the initial value with an empty array

```
public paymentList : <type>[] = [];
```